# Calling an admin block from xml layout issue

Tags: blocks, xml

This is the content of my custom module, config.xml file:

```
<adminhtml>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <mymodule>
                    <file>homepage.xml</file>
                </mymodule>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </adminhtml>
```

this is the content of the layout/homepage.xml file from

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_manage_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="mynamespace_mymodule/adminhtml_banner" name="mynamespace_mymodule_banner" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_manage_index>
</layout>
```

This is the content of my controller Mynamespace/Mymodule/controllers/Adminhtml/ManageController.php

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Adminhtml_ManageController extends Mage_Adminhtml_Controller_Action
{
    public function indexAction()
    {  
        $this->loadLayout();
        $this->_initAction()->renderLayout();
    } 
}
```

and the content of the Mynamespace/Mymodule/Block/Adminhtml/Banner.php

```
class Mynamespace_Mymodule_Block_Adminhtml_Banner extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Container
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        echo 1; exit();
//....
    }
}
```

My problem is that it doesn't access the block. I put an exit() there . But I cannot get there. Why ? What am I missing ? thx

Comment: Please replace Mynamespace/Mymodule/Block/AdminHtml/Banner.php to and the content of the Mynamespace/Mymodule/Block/Adminhtml/Banner.php

Comment: Mynamespace/Mymodule/controllers/AdminHtml/ManageController.php to Mynamespace/Mymodule/controllers/Adminhtml/ManageController.php

Comment: @Abdul I don't understand. Can you give more details!

Comment: rename folder name "AdminHtml" => "Adminhtml"

Comment: sorry my mistake, it is Adminhtml not AdminHTML, from the start, I updated my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Rename folder name "AdminHtml" => "Adminhtml"**

Please replace from

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_manage_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="mynamespace_mymodule/adminhtml_banner" name="mynamespace_mymodule_banner" />
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_manage_index>
</layout>
```

**To**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <mymodule_adminhtml_manage_index>
        <reference name="content">
            <block type="mynamespace_mymodule/adminhtml_banner" name="mynamespace_mymodule_banner" />
        </reference>
    </mymodule_adminhtml_manage_index>
</layout>
```

Comment: nothing changed I still don't get  to echo 1; exit(); . any other idea ?  thx

Comment: can you please vote me and assp my ans?

Comment: its work. but instead of mymodule, i must write mynamespace. please update  your post with my suggestion and I will accept your post as answer. thx